# Unable to plot png in gnuplot

Tags: ubuntu, unix, png, gnuplot

i need to plot png files in gnuplot 4.6.3 and/or 4.6.4.I am unable to do so as set term does not list "png" as an option.

system information is

Linux masterx-Studio-1535 3.5.0-27-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 20:00:05 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

set term gives me following options

```
     canvas  HTML Canvas object
          cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
      context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
        corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW
         dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
          dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
        eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment
          emf  Enhanced Metafile format
        emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials
     epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
          fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor
         gpic  GPIC -- Produce graphs in groff using the gpic preprocessor
      hp2623A  HP2623A and maybe others
       hp2648  HP2648 and HP2647
         hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
       imagen  Imagen laser printer
        latex  LaTeX picture environment
           mf  Metafont plotting standard
          mif  Frame maker MIF 3.00 format
           mp  MetaPost plotting standard
         pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
      pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
        pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
     pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
          qms  QMS/QUIC Laser printer (also Talaris 1200 and others)
        regis  REGIS graphics language
          svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics driver
      tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators
      tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals
      texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
         tgif  TGIF X11 [mode] [x,y] [dashed] ["font" [fontsize]]
     tkcanvas  Tk/Tcl canvas widget [perltk] [interactive]
         tpic  TPIC -- LaTeX picture environment with tpic \specials
      unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
        vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator
          x11  X11 Window System
         xlib  X11 Window System (gnulib_x11 dump)
        xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: Can you improve the question with console outputs, operating system information..? Just telling the program version may be making the question more specific than needed and limiting the scope of answerers.

Comment: i tried both version of gnuplot, but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I wanted to do a quick plot, I used the `graph` utility from the Debian package 'plotutils'. When I needed a fast way of making higher quality graphics than those `graph` provided, and when working with easily scriptable data flows, I used matplotlib for Python. That may be because finding `gnuplot` a little bit hard to use... I really don't remember.

**However the sensible answer here I think that is that if you want/need to stick to `gnuplot`, note that in your output lies svg *the W3C Scalable Vector Graphics driver*. Please check [a lot of online resources available](http://jasonhardin.com/gimp-svg-to-png-script/) for svg to png conversion**. Hopefully you will be able to `gnuplot` to svg and then convert them to png.

But anyway, if you care about plots, you may test more plot utils! Do a little `graph` testing on your own and check online resources for [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), [the `trend` live graph generator](http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/trend/) and, if you do web development, [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/), [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) and a whole bunch of other JavaScript libraries for plots charting.

Comment: Honestly, for publication quality graphs I would recommend `gnuplot` with the `cairolatex`, `epslatex`, `postscript` or `pdfcairo` terminal. No need to convert anything to png or similar bitmap formats.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer towards a more neutral point of view. Btw are you [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/229096/) Christoph?

Comment: No, I'm not that Christoph :)